# It is better to tell a user that is banned or it is better to disguise that he is banned?

Tags: subscription

I'm building an app and in order to prevent that the banned users roam controls it is better to tell a user that is banned or it is better to disguise that is banned?
For example, I could say that there was a problem to the system during subscription if I discovered that the email is banned.

Comment: what does the application do?

Comment: FWIW,  it sounds like what you're trying to implement is called [Ghost Banning](https://pingler.com/blog/what-is-ghost-banning-and-how-can-you-avoid-it-as-a-marketer/)

Comment: Dont lie to users. It's that simple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Banned user tries to log in − show a “Banned” message or a generic “Cannot log you in”?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/86634/banned-user-tries-to-log-in-%e2%88%92-show-a-banned-message-or-a-generic-cannot-log-y)

Answer (score 4):

It's better to tell them that their account is banned (or suspended).

Otherwise you will have to deal with customer support issues trying to figure out why their account isn't working. Only to find out they been banned.

Comment: I think if a user read that the site have a problem think to give up the idea to register. Instead if I tell he was banned he can change the email or use a proxy if I ban his IP and troll again.

Comment: Assuming the user is a legitimate poster caught in a spam filter, you're probably right.  Assuming the user is a spammer who'll just take a new account as soon as they know their current account is banned, shadow banning is a better practice.  Without additional knowledge of what user3482682 is maintaining, it's difficult to say which one may be more reasonable.

Comment: Applying a "ghost-ban" programmatically will likely have some "by-catch:" it will stop not only spammers but also some legitimate posters. Ensure that there's a way to appeal or a mechanism for moderator review.